# Turning off the camera in the OnNavigatedFrom() method in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to ensure that when the user navigates away from a particular page, the camera is disposed of.

To turn on the camera I make a call to `await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync()`. If however the OnNavigatedFrom() method is called before the OpenAsync() method finishes, I have no way to dispose of the camera, and it will remain turned on.

What is the correct way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a singleton, or an static manager class for that kind of operations, so you can call that class to initialize the camera, and to close it whenever you want. Then there you can keep a flag on that class that you use to say if the camera was cancelled, or something like that, so that way it can check after the async method, if the camera was cancelled.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From here: https://github.com/slodge/BallControl/blob/master/Cirrious.Sphero.WorkBench/Cirrious.Sphero.WorkBench.UI.WindowsPhone/Views/SpheroView.xaml.cs

```
private AudioVideoCaptureDevice _cam;
...
     protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            _isNavigatingFrom = true;
            if (CameraIsRecording)
            {
/*
var task = DoStopRecording();
task.Start();
task.Wait();
*/
            }
            TheMoveJoystick.StopJoystick();
            ViewModel.AccelMovement.EnsureAccelerometerIsOnCommand.Execute(false);
            ViewModel.Speech.EnsureSpeechIsOn.Execute(false);
            ViewModel.AccelMovement.PropertyChanged -= AccelMovementOnPropertyChanged;
            _hackTimer.Stop();
            if (_cam != null)
            {
                _cam.Dispose();
                _cam = null;
            }
            _isNavigatingFrom = false;
            base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
        }
```

Comment: this code assumes that OpenAsync() is done and later does `await _cam.StopRecordingAsync()` in DoStopRecording()